# How to get the distance from SceneDepth data in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, arkit, ios14

I am going to access `ARDepthData`in Xamarin.iOS. So far my code is like this.

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        if (!ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.SupportsFrameSemantics(ARFrameSemantics.SceneDepth))
        {
            UIAlertController alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Unsupported Device", "SceneDepth is not available on current device", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertController alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Yay", "Congratulations! Your device supports SceneDepth", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
            configuration = new ARWorldTrackingConfiguration
            {
                FrameSemantics = ARFrameSemantics.SceneDepth,
                PlaneDetection = ARPlaneDetection.None
                
            };
            sceneView.Session.Delegate = new SessionDelegate();
            sceneView.Session = session;
            sceneView.Session.Run(configuration);
     }
```

My `SessionDelegate` class is like this.

```
 public class SessionDelegate : ARSessionDelegate
{
    public SessionDelegate()
    {
    }

    public override void DidUpdateFrame(ARSession session, ARFrame frame)
    {
        base.DidUpdateFrame(session, frame);
        Console.WriteLine("Frame has been updated");
        if (frame.SceneDepth != null)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Depth data is not null");
        }
    }
}
```

My app just opens up the camera view. The above delegate is not firing. What am I missing here? When does this delegate fire and how can I get the distance from
SceneDepthData?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, do you have a look at [this official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios12-scanninganddetecting3dobjects/) to know how to use ARKit in iOS?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes I checked. But It is nothing about ARDepthData

Comment: Okey, which device is used to test? The `SceneDepth` need the device owns LiDAR sensor. In addition, if the `DidUpdateFrame` method works, you need to comment this line code:`base.DidUpdateFrame(session, frame);`, then it will be build successfully.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I am using iPad pro 2020(2nd generation) which has LiDAR. I checked by commenting the `base.DidUpdateFrame`. But still the delegate is not firing.

Comment: Okey, because I have no supported device to test, if I can test that will update here.